# Comparing object values from DB with csv content

Tags: php, arrays, object, csv

I have a function which gets me all students enrolled on a course on my local db. I need to cross check their usernames with usernames from a csv and output the ones who are NOT in the csv

Here's the output of the function:

```
Array (
    [as.domingos] => stdClass Object ( [username] => as.domingos )
    [m.menas] => stdClass Object ( [username] => m.menas )
    [m.bexiga] => stdClass Object ( [username] => m.bexiga )
    [spm] => stdClass Object ( [username] => spm ) )
```

And here's the csv format:

```
username;email;course1
userA;a@gmail.com;ABC
userB;b@gmail.com;ABC
m.menas;m.menas@gmail.com;ABC
m.bexiga;m.bexiga@gmail.com;ABC
spm;spm@gmail.com;ABC
```

My first thought was calling *array_diff* but it's not working. In this example above, the output would be as.domingos, because it's not in the csv.

```
 $fp=fopen('sample.csv','r');
    $numberofquitters=0;

    $enrolinfo=' ';
    fgetcsv($fp,1000,";");
    while(($data=fgetcsv($fp,1000,";"))!==FALSE){
    if(array_diff((array)$xpta->username,$data)){
        //echo $xpto->username;
        $enrolinfo=get_string('quitter','local_ecoclipaluno');
        $numberofquitters++;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Cheers.